# Point positioning inside rectangle with only two known vertexes

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

I'm working on a js widget, and I've come across a positioning problem, which I can't seem to solve with my limited geometry knowledge or by help of Wikipedia/google.

I have a quadrilateral rectangle, which is positioned at an angle. I know its **two opposite vertexes** and **width/height ratio**. And there's a point on it, which coordinates I also know.
I need to find how far (in %s of width/height) is that point from rectangle's sides. Is it possible to do so?
[image]

Comment: There are two same sized rectangles that can fit the two points. Without some extra information, for example is point 1 at the top left of the rectangle, you will have two solutions. If you know what corner the point is at then distance between the two points gives the `hypot` of right triangle with `adj` and `opp` lengths W and H. From there you can solve for all points of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Having two corners `P1 = (x1,y1)` and `P2 = (x2,y2)` and point Q, you can find diagonal length

```
dx = (x2 - x1)
dy = (y2 - y1) 
dlen = sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)
```

and unit direction vector

```
dx = dx / dlen
dy = dy / dlen
```

and center of rectangle

```
cx = x1 + dx/2
cy = y1 + dy/2
```

Width and height  (with known `r = w/h` ratio)

```
w = dlen / sqrt(1 + r^2)
h = w / r
```

Now we need direction of side of length `w`. Note that given information does not allow to choose exact rectangle orientation from two possible cases.

Angle between diagonal and side

```
sina = r / sqrt(1 + r^2)
cosa = 1 / sqrt(1 + r^2)
```

Side direction vector

```
wx = dx * cosa - dy * sina
wy = dx * sina  + dy * cosa
```

and for the second orientation

```
wx' = dx * cosa + dy * sina
wy' = -dx * sina + dy * cosa
```

The second side vector

```
hx = -wy
hy = wx
```

Now we can find length of projection of point p onto sides `W` and `H` using dot product

```
qx = q.x - x1
qy = q.y - y1

qw = qx * wx + qy * wy
qh = qx * hx + qy * hy
```

The last values are coordinates in `W-H` basis, so value `qw` varies from 0 for points at the "left" to `w` for points at the "right" side. You can divide these values by `w` and `h` to get percent values.

Note again - there are two possible rectangles and correspondingly two positions of point `Q`